# Send and receive uint32_t over a socket via iovec

Tags: c++, sockets, unix-socket

I'm trying to send a uint_32t type variable over iovec sturct over unix domain socket.

My iovec declaration:

```
uint32_t request_id = 123456;
struct iovec io = { .iov_base = &request_id, .iov_len = sizeof(uint32_t) };
```

on the receiving side:

```
char dup[4];
struct iovec io = { .iov_base = dup, .iov_len = sizeof(dup) };
msg.msg_iov = &io;
```

When I print `msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base` I get a different number every time.

```
printf("msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base = %d\n", msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base); => 723905316
```

I guess something is off with bytes-to-uint32 conversion?

Comment: Could you show the exact code used to print the number, and the exact output seen. Seems to me the error is more likely to be in the printing than the conversion.

Comment: @john added print info

Comment: `%d` is not the correct conversion specifier for a `void*` - use `%p` - or `std::cout << msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base << '\n';`

Comment: @guygrinberger So the problem is that you are printing the address of the receiving buffer, not the integer at all. In fact you aren't converting anything on the receiving side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I print msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base I get a different number every time.

Yes, on the sending side it's the address of `request_id` and on the receiving side it's address of `dup`. These addresses do however not matter. They are only used to tell `writev` and `readv` where to read/write the data and they will often be different each time you start the programs.

Example:

Sender:

```cpp
uint32_t request_id = htonl(123456); // to network byte order from host byte order
iovec io = { .iov_base = &request_id, .iov_len = sizeof(uint32_t) };
writev(fd, &io, 1);
```

Receiver:

```cpp
uint32_t request_id;
iovec io = { .iov_base = &request_id, .iov_len = sizeof(uint32_t) };
readv(fd, &io, 1);
request_id = ntohl(request_id); // from network byte order to host byte order
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I needed. endian wise, are the bytes sent with iov_base are the first in the message?

Comment: @guygrinberger You're welcome! If you use network byte order as I did above, they will be sent in big-endian order, that is, the most significant byte will be sent first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing the address, not the integer.

Assuming no endianess issues, then something like this should work

```
printf("msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base = %d\n", *(int32_t*)msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base);
```

This code does assume that `%d` can successfully print a `int32_t` something I don't think is guaranteed to be true. If that's a problem you could try this

```
int temp = *(int32_t*)msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base;
printf("msg.msg_iov[0].iov_base = %d\n", temp);
```